# How to fix NumberFormatException error when I use Integer variable when trying to parse " 97" to int?

Tags: java, parsing, exception, integer, numberformatexception

I am [solving this comps question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element/problem), upon exceeding time limit I decided to keep track of the max integer element rather than searching for it every time. The new code throws the exception the line below case 1. maiks refers to the max value inside the stack.

old code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    Stack<Integer> stk=new Stack<Integer>();
    char a;
    int input;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a=(char)br.read();
        switch(a){
            case '1':
                br.skip(1);
                input=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                stk.add(input);
                break;
            case '2':
                stk.pop();
                br.readLine();
                break;
            case '3':
                System.out.println(Collections.max(stk));
                br.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

New code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    Stack<Integer> stk=new Stack<Integer>();
    char a;
    Integer maiks=0;
    int input=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a=(char)br.read();
        switch(a){
            case '1':
                input=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                stk.add(input);
                if(input>maiks){
                    maiks=input;
                }
                break;
            case '2':
                Integer p=stk.pop();
                if(p==maiks){
                    maiks=Collections.max(stk);
                }
                br.readLine();
                break;
            case '3':
                System.out.println(maiks);
                br.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception thrown in the new code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 97"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Solution.main(Solution.java:17)
```

Comment: you'll need to remove that space, to make it become "97". 9 is a numerical value, so is 7 and so is 97. " " on the other hand, is not.

Comment: @Stultuske parseInt should work with or without space but I skipped the space. Then I am getting a NoSuchElement exception at maiks=Collections.max(stk); in case 2

Comment: "parseInt should work with or without space" .. no, it shouldn't, and it won't. your case 2 is not really related to what happens in your case 1, so that's a different matter alltogether.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to parse a string that is not numeric - in your case its " 97". The prepending space is causing the problem. The NoSuchElementException you are getting after fixing it is another problem, and is probably caused by one of your readLine() statements.